# override a method of a class with an method from another class

Tags: python, class

I have following code:

```py
    class SomeClass:
        def __init__(self) -> None:
            pass
    
        def some_class_function(self, par):
            print(par)
    
    class SomeOtherClass:
        def __init__(self) -> None:
            pass
    
        def some_other_class_function(self, par):
            print(par+1)
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        sc = SomeClass()
        sc.some_class_function = SomeOtherClass.some_other_class_function
        sc.some_class_function(1)
```

When I execute the code I get

```
TypeError: some_other_class_function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'par'
```

How can I override the method of the first class with the method of the second class properly?

Comment: I suspect that this might work if you replace the second line of the main script with `sc.some_class_function = SomeOtherClass().some_other_class_function`, adding in those parentheses.

Comment: Do you want to override it for one instance only, or for the class in general?

Comment: @Ben That's going to bind `self` to `SomeOtherClass()` though, not to `sc`.

Comment: @deceze Based on the accepted answer, that seems to be the desired behavior

Comment: @Ben Since neither method interacts with `self`, OP may just not have discovered that side effect yet…

Comment: @Ben Ah I think I just discovered it.... Is it possible that self is still sc and not sco?

Comment: @michaelgr22 You can redefine `sc.some_class_function` to be another function that uses `sc` as self, but there's no good way to use the existing `SomeOtherClass` to do that.

Comment: @michaelgr22 If `SomeClass` is a subclass of `SomeOtherClass`, then you could access `some_other_class_function` while using `sc` as "self".

Comment: @Ben inheritance is unfortunately not an option for me. Do you have an example for the first approach, when some_other_class_function is not a function of SomeOtherClass?

Comment: @michaelgr22 See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2982/2476977)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noted in the comments, you are interested in adding method that will use `sc` as the "self" instance.

To that end, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2982/2476977). To summarize, you can either add a function to the class definition (affecting future instances of the same class), or bind the function to the particular instance.

As an example, consider the following class and function.

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.phrase = "hello world"
    def func(self):
        print("this is the old method")

def test_func(self):
    print(self.phrase)
```

For the first approach, we could do the following

```
test = Test()
Test.func = test_func
test.func()
```

Note that future instances of Test will have this function as an attribute. For example, running `Test().func()` will still result in the same output, even though the method is being used on a new class instance.

For the second, we could do the following.

```
import types

test = Test()
test.func = types.MethodType(test_func, test)
test.func()
```

In this case, running the line `Test().func()` will result in the output "this is the old method" because `func` has not been overwritten for new instances.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the class to call its method.

```
sc = SomeClass()
sco = SomeOtherClass() # initialize the second call to call it's method
sc.some_class_function = sco.some_other_class_function
sc.some_class_function(1)
```

Comment: Thank you that's the thing I forgot!